# Assign php code to smarty template engine

Tags: php, smarty, assign

I make a new website for my company and i want to use smarty (v3.1.29) for it. Now the problem is that we **store** the **code** for all pages **in our database** (home, products, downloads, ...). Some pages contains PHP inline functions like:

```
<?php include("functions.php"); ?>    

<p> Hello <?php echo printWorldInColor(); ?> </p>
```

In my template (.tpl) file I have a div-section to load the content from our database:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      {$content}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So my code looks like this afterwards:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <?php include("functions.php"); ?>    

      <p> Hello <?php echo printWorldInColor(); ?> </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way that smarty processes the PHP-code before parsing it?

**Hint: I dont want to edit my template file. I just want to parse the database content to my content-section of the website.**

What i tried:

- saved database-content into a string and replaced PHP-tags with smarty-PHP-tags, then assign it to the template
- SmartyBC-Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in Smarty. Also running php code stored in the database sounds like a terrible idea. But if for some reason you have to go on with this nonsense (and considering that you can't use eval), you can try this:

1. Read the php code from the database.
2. Save to a temporal php file
3. Turn on output buffering with ob_start()
4. include the file you have created
5. assign the output to a variable with ob_get_clean()
6. assign the variable to the template

But if I was you, I would try to do the project in another way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't think about to rework the whole site and I dont know why the pages are stored in a database. I think I make a new site first without that database and then I edit the database/tables for my needs.

Comment: Now I know why we stored the code in database. It has something to do with our update-system. In our intranet we can update the website and upload the changes directly to the public website database. Then the public website loads the page content from the database.